# Как вызвать функцию класса внутри js класса

Tags: javascript, классы, ecmascript-6

Например:

```
 class Car(){
    weight(){
      alert('100kg');
    }
    getWeight(){
      this.weight()   //не работает
   }
}
```

Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: уберите круглые скобки после `class Car`

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. проблема вызвана опечаткой

```js
class Car {
    weight(){
      alert('100kg');
    }
    getWeight(){
      this.weight()   //не работает
   }
}
(new Car()).getWeight();
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
class Car {
    weight() {
      console.log('100kg');
    }
    getWeight(){
      this.weight();
   }
}

var car = new Car;
car.getWeight();
```